# App Store forcing me to pay twice for the same app but on different devices

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, mac-appstore

I bought a paid app on my iMac, and a few months later tried to download it on my iPhone but it’s forcing me to pay *again* for it. I thought the App Store linked purchases on multiple devices?

Answer (score 32):

Mac apps and iOS apps are completely separate.

If you purchase a Mac app, you can install it on any of your Macs. Likewise for an iOS app, which can be installed on any of your iPhone, iPad or iPod touch devices. Mac apps can't be run on an iOS device and vice versa — they are independent systems which link purchases independently.

Comment: Don't forget iPad only "HD" versions of iPhone apps which are also separate App Store entries requiring their own purchases.